# encrypting traffic from legacy devices

Tags: encryption, network, iot

I have a deployment of a few hundred meters that I'm walking into and all traffic is required to be encrypted with TLS. The manufacture of the meter will not update these meters to include an encryption feature so, we're left alone to solve the problem.

I was hoping there was such thing as a small encryption pass-through device that would simply encrypt all the traffic with an input\output port without requiring an IP address change but, I don't think that technology exists.

What do you think my options are (VPN, hardware, other)?

Comment: Any site-to-site VPN solution will do that

Comment: I am in no way, shape or form associated with the company, nor have I ever used any of their products, but [Senetas](http://www.senetas.com/) makes layer 2 encryption devices that might do what you're hoping for.